# Is there hotswap on the new AWS EventBridge Scheduler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, aws-cdk, hotswap

EventBridge Scheduler was released on 2022/11. It is basically a powerful version of the existing EventBridge scheduled rules, with more scalability, timezone support, time window schedules, etc. [Introducing Amazon EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/)

And i'm wondering if it's possible to use this new scheduler EventBridge Scheduler to trigger a Lambda function and perform a "hotswap" operation on deploy with cdk.

Comment: What do you mean by "hotswap operation" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately no, i did some test and if the cron value change it re deploy from scratch.

For those who didn't know what is a hotswap deployment:
https://cloudash.dev/blog/hotswap-cdk-deployments